# Core Data NSFetchRequest sorted unique results

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have these 2 Core Data entities :

1) Contact : name / ... / history (To many relationship with the 'Event' entity)

2) Event : date / contact (To one relationship with the 'Contact' entity)

contact is the inverse of history (and vice versa)

Now I want to retrieve the contact property of all the events sorted by the date property and without contact duplicates.

I have tried these 2 approaches without success :

```
// This is a fetch request for the 'Event' entity
NSFetchRequest *contactsRequest = ...
```

1)

```
[contactsRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"contact"]];
[contactsRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[contactsRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[contactsRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]]];
```

Here the contacts are unique but the sort descriptor is just ignored, because I don't fetch the 'date' property.

2) So I changed line 1 to

```
[contactsRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"contact", @"date"]];
```

Now it's the other way around, the contacts are not unique (it's the (contact,date) pair that's unique), but the results are sorted.

I just can't figure out how to have both unique and sorted contacts.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW, you ought to be passing `NSPropertyDescription` objects to `setPropertiesToFetch:` according to the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/propertiesToFetch)

Answer (score 0):

Use `returnsDistinctResults` to fetch only the distinct results, unsorted.  Then use `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` to sort the results.

Comment: for returnsDistinctResults to give me unique contacts, I can't fetch the 'date' property, otherwise I fall in case 2) (contacts are not unique (it's the (contact,date) pair that's unique)), So if I get the distinct results, unsorted (case 1)), I end up with an array of distinct contacts, but with no date property to sort with.

Comment: If I can retrieve an array of (contact, date) pairs unsorted but with unique contacts, the problem would be solved.

Comment: Meh, yeah, that's my bad.  It seems like you'll probably wind up having to just fetch all the contacts sorted and filter for duplicate contacts.  It's fairly easy to do and there's a lot of questions and answers here on the subject.

Comment: That's what I currently do actually, I just thought there should be a way to do all the sorting and filtering with Core Data. Thanks for the answering anyway :)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656227/retrieving-a-unique-result-set-with-core-data) seems to be exactly the same and has an answer that was accepted, but I think it's what you're already trying.

Comment: Reviewing the reference, I don't think it's possible.  `returnsDistinctResults` explicitly states: "returns only distinct values for the fields specified by `propertiesToFetch`"